# How to get a form value in order process?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, payment, checkbox

I have created a new small module to add a checkbox on last step of order process:

[image]

The value will transfer over payment JSON:

[image]

In the generated PaymentExtensionInterface I have the getter and setter methods:

```
<?php
namespace Magento\Quote\Api\Data;

/**
 * ExtensionInterface class for @see \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface
 */
interface PaymentExtensionInterface extends \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttributesInterface
{
    /**
     * @return boolean|null
     */
    public function getTestCheckboxValue();

    /**
     * @param boolean $testCheckboxValue
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setTestCheckboxValue($testCheckboxValue);
```

But the question is how can I get the value in the event "sales_order_save_commit_after" in an other module like this class?

```
<?php

use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface;
use Magento\Payment\Observer\AbstractDataAssignObserver;
use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface;
use Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface;

class Test extends AbstractObserver
{
    protected $_request;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
    ) {
        $this->_request = $request;
    }

    protected function _execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {

        $order = $observer->getData('order');
```

Comment: I update my answer @Michael, check if it works now for you

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

You can also add a checkbox in a knockoutjs html template and save the value in a controller to your quote table, probably this is not the preferable Magento2 way.

Add your checkbox in a html knockoutjs template, I will do it in the design folder (you can also do it in your module, just to keep it simple here): `Magento_Checkout/web/template/form/element/email.html`

```
            <div class="field">
                <label class="label" for="checkbox-custom">
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Checkbox Custom:'"></span>
                </label>
                <div class="control checkbox-custom">
                    <input
                            type="checkbox"
                            name="checkbox-custom"
                            id="checkbox-custom"
                            data-bind="afterRender: bindToCheckbox"/>
                </div>
            </div>
```

After add in design folder:

```
Magento_Checkout/templates/onepage.phtml
```

Add in the end of the file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function bindToCheckbox() {
            jQuery("#checkbox-custom").change(function() {
                if(this.checked) {
                    var url = '/checkbox/checkbox/checkbox';
                    var data = {
                        checked : "check",
                    };

                    jQuery.get(url, data, function(response) {
                        console.warn(response);
                    });
                }
                else {
                    var url = '/checkbox/checkbox/checkbox';
                    var data = {
                        checked : "not",
                    };

                    jQuery.get(url, data, function(response) {
                        console.warn(response);
                    });
                }
            });
        }
</script>
```

Create a module with a route `< Vendor>/Checkbox/etc/frontend/routes.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="checkbox" frontName="checkbox">
            <module name="Vendor_Checkbox"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Add your controller: `< Vendor>/Checkbox/Controller/Checkbox/Checkbox.php`

```
<?php

namespace < Vendor>\Checkbox\Controller\Checkbox;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository;

class Checkbox extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var Session
     */
    private $checkoutSession;
    /**
     * @var QuoteRepository
     */
    private $quoteRepository;

    /**
     * Checkbox constructor.
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Session $checkoutSession
     * @param QuoteRepository $quoteRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Session $checkoutSession,
        QuoteRepository $quoteRepository
    ){
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $checkbox= $this->getRequest()->getParam('checked');

        if($checkbox == "check"){
            $checkbox = "1";
        }
        else{
            $checkbox = "0";
        }

        $quoteId = $this->checkoutSession->getQuoteId();

        $quote = $this->quoteRepository->get($quoteId);

        $quote->setCustomCheckbox($checkbox);

        $quote->save();

        die($checkbox);
    }
}
```

Create a setup script for new fields in quote and sales_order tables `< Vendor>/Checkbox/Setup/UpgradeSchema.php`

```
<?php


namespace < Vendor>\Checkbox\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{

    /**
     * Upgrades DB schema for a module
     *
     * @param SchemaSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     * @return void
     */
    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1') < 0) {
            $setup->startSetup();

            $setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
                $setup->getTable('sales_order'),
                'custom_checkbox',
                [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                    'length' => '11',
                    'nullable' => false,
                    'default' => '0'
                ]
            );

            $setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
                $setup->getTable('quote'),
                'custom_checkbox',
                [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                    'length' => '11',
                    'nullable' => false,
                    'default' => '0'

                ]
            );


            $setup->endSetup();
        }
    }
}
```

Set the module version to 1.0.1 in `module.xml`
Run `bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Create  `< Vendor>/Checkbox/etc/events.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">

    <event name="sales_order_place_after">
        <observer name="place_order_after_checkbox" instance="< Vendor>\Checkbox\Observer\Orderplaceafter" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Than you can get the data from your custom checkbox in the event, here I also set the data in the sales_order table, what Magento 2 doesn't do automatically.
Create `< Vendor>/Checkbox/Observer/Orderplaceafter.php`

```
<?php


namespace < Vendor>\Checkbox\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository;
use Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingFactory;

class Orderplaceafter implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var QuoteRepository
     */
    private $quoteRepository;
    /**
     * @var ShippingInformationInterface
     */
    private $shippingInformation;
    /**
     * @var ShippingFactory
     */
    private $shippingFactory;

    /**
     * Orderplaceafter constructor.
     * @param QuoteRepository $quoteRepository
     * @param ShippingInformationInterface $shippingInformation
     * @param ShippingFactory $shippingFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        QuoteRepository $quoteRepository,
        ShippingInformationInterface $shippingInformation,
        ShippingFactory $shippingFactory
    ){
        $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
        $this->shippingInformation = $shippingInformation;
        $this->shippingFactory = $shippingFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @return void
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getOrder();
        $quote = $this->quoteRepository->get($order->getQuoteId());

        $order->setData('custom_checkbox', $quote->getCustomCheckbox());

        $order->save();
    }
}
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work. I get always the error message like this: 
"Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\\Sales\\Api\\Data\\OrderExtension::getTestCheckboxValue()"
I have tried so many things...

Comment: Try adding $order->getPayment()->getExtensionAttributes()

Comment: I have tried this too. Then I get the output "Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderPaymentExtension Object
(
    [_data:protected] => Array
        (
        )

)"
But I can not access to getTestCheckboxValue() or also to getAgreementIds().

Comment: Could you post your extension_attributes.xml ?

Comment: I have post it on the answer.

Comment: I updated my question @Michael , try if you can get the value like this..

Comment: Thanks, I had the same idea this morning but magento can not find this get method. That is so strange for me. I clean always caches and delete generated files. I'm new in Magento 2 and may be I have to go a complete other way to add a checkbox in checkout process to read in an observer class? But what is the right way?

Comment: You can check this one from devdocs https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_field.html

Comment: I have create a new model and have exactly done the stuff which are in your linked doc. But It also doesn't work! The text field is ok and the string value will transfer over the ajax object. But I can not access the value! I have no idea what can be wrong?

Comment: Thank you so much! But I have found an another way for me. I have use a Plugin to get the value in the SavePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder method. I have saved the value in a helper class so I can access the value in my observer class.

Answer (score 0):

This is my extension_attributes.xml:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface">
        <attribute code="test_checkbox_value" type="boolean" />
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```